# U Substitution Question [Why won't this work?]

Tags: calculus

I see that this can be solved easily by expanding the $(1 - x^2)^2$, but when I tried U-Substitution I couldn't get very far. Any info about why an integral like this can't be solved with u-sub would be much appreciated.

> $$\begin{align} V &= \int_{-1}^{1} A(x) \, dx & \text{General slicing method.} \\  &= \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\pi}{2} (1-x^2)^2 \, dx & \text{Substitute for $A(x)$.} \\ &= \frac{\pi}{2} \int_{-1}^{1} (1-2x^2+x^4) \, dx & \text{Expand integrand.} \\ &= \frac{8\pi}{15} & \text{Evaluate.}\end{align}$$

Comment: Image doesn't work.

Comment: It could but it's not necessarily going to be nice. What choice did you make for $u$ in your $u$-sub?

Comment: I chose  $(1 - x^2)^2$ for u

Comment: @ao2130 Are you *required* to use $u$-substitution for this problem? Because $u$-sub certainly does not work for every problem, possibly even ones that can be expanded polynomial-wise.

Comment: I am not required to use U-Sub, however am I trying to understand when it is appropriate to use it. I saw the composition $(1 - x^2)^2$ and assumed that U-Sub would be a viable method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you wish to evaluate $$\int_{-1}^1\frac\pi2\left(1-x^2\right)^2\,dx,$$ and your thought was to make the substitution $u=1-x^2,$ if I'm understanding you correctly. Unfortunately, this substitution gives us no way* to translate the $dx$ into terms of $du.$ Since $u=1-x^2,$ then $$\frac{du}{dx}=-2x.\tag{$\star$}$$ Unfortunately (and forgive the pun), there is no $x$ factor in this integrand, so we're out of luck.

> *As Andres points out in the comments below, this isn't true. I should say that there is no *convenient* way to do this that is guaranteed to help us.

---

Suppose we were evaluating $$\int_{-1}^1\frac{\pi x}2\left(1-x^2\right)^2\,dx,$$ instead. Then we could use $u=1-x^2,$ and since by $(\star)$ we have $$x=-\frac12\frac{du}{dx},$$ then we have $$\begin{align}\int_{-1}^1\frac{\pi x}2\left(1-x^2\right)^2\,dx &= \int_{-1}^1\frac\pi2\left(1-x^2\right)^2\cdot x\,dx\\ &= \int_{1-(-1)^2}^{1-1^2}\frac\pi2u^2\cdot-\frac12\frac{du}{dx}\,dx\\ &= \int_0^0-\frac\pi4u^2\,du\\ &= 0.\end{align}$$ This *does* happen to be the correct *value* of the integral, but we need to make certain that our $u$-substitutions are one-to-one on the interval of integration, or [we can run into problems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351355/integrating-by-substitution/351370#351370). Technically, we should really split the integral up into two separate integrals over $[-1,0]$ and $[0,1]$ (both of which are intervals on which $u=1-x^2$ is one-to-one) before making the substitution. This gives us $$\begin{align}\int_{-1}^1\frac{\pi x}2\left(1-x^2\right)^2\,dx &= \int_{-1}^0\frac{\pi x}2\left(1-x^2\right)^2\,dx + \int_0^1\frac{\pi x}2\left(1-x^2\right)^2\,dx \\ &= \int_{-1}^0\frac\pi2\left(1-x^2\right)^2\cdot x\,dx + \int_0^1\frac\pi2\left(1-x^2\right)^2\cdot x\,dx\\ &= \int_{1-(-1)^2}^{1-0^2}\frac\pi2u^2\cdot-\frac12\frac{du}{dx}\,dx + \int_{1-0^2}^{1-1^2}\frac\pi2u^2\cdot-\frac12\frac{du}{dx}\,dx\\ &= \int_0^1-\frac\pi4u^2\,du + \int_1^0-\frac\pi4u^2\,du\\ &= \int_0^1-\frac\pi4u^2\,du + -\int_0^1-\frac\pi4u^2\,du\\ &= 0.\end{align}$$ Even more simply, we can note that $\frac{\pi x}2\left(1-x^2\right)^2$ is an odd integrable function and that $[-1,1]$ is symmetric about the origin, so the integral will automatically be $0.$

Comment: You're quite welcome. You should take a look at the expanded answer for some key cautionary notes.

Comment: It is not quite correct to say that we cannot translate $dx$ in terms of $du$: First, replace the integral for $2\int_0^1$, so $u=(1-x^2)^2$ is invertible. Then $1-x^2=\sqrt u$, so $x^2=1-\sqrt u$, $x=\sqrt{1-\sqrt u}$, and we can find $dx$ in terms of $du$. It is certainly a messy substitution which may not help us with the integral at hand, but that is a different issue.

Comment: @Andres: Fair point. Addendum appended for accuracy.